# Python project giving me ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'teste'

Tags: python

I have two folders each one with a `file.py` inside (`root project > src/` with `main.py` and `teste/` with `t.py`).
I'm trying to import the `t.py` in my `main.py`, but I'm having the following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'teste'

The code of my `main.py` is:

```py
import teste.t as t_
t_.hi()
```

The `hi()` just prints a "Hi" on the console. I checked if Python is on the path and is; I tried to use the `SETPYTHONPATH=`. or the folder path, everything.
I also tried to use the `sys.append` and nothing works.

Why?

Answer (score 1):

Your python process wants to import "`teste`". But it cannot find a file named "`teste.py`" and also not a directory called "`teste`" with a file called "`__init__.py`" inside.

Whenever you want to import something, make sure that the file to import is reachable by python. The easiest way for python to see such a file is if it is in the same directory as the file that you started using the command "`python myfile.py`".

There's another error: you wrote "`import teste.t as t_`" - which is a bit unusual, but okay. BUT in the next line you call "`t.hi()`" - but "`t`" isn't anywhere declared. Did you mean "`t_.hi()`"?
Nevertheless, first make sure that Python finds a directory called "`teste`"...

Comment: Well, starting for the `t.hi()` was my mistake, I used t_.hi() in the code.  About the first thing, even if I try to do `from teste import t as t_` with the `__init__.py` file , it gives me the same error. I don't why teste folder is not recognized...

Comment: please post your full folder + file structure as well as the content of the relevant files, otherwise it's just guesswork for people who would be willing to help.